# Idiomatic way to know if an istream starts with a string in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, istream

Suppose you have two strings and you want to know whether one is a prefix of the other. Here is one way to do it in C++:

```
std::string s = ...;
std::string prefix = ...;
bool sStartsWithPrefix = std::equal(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), s.begin());
```

But suppose that instead of `s` you have an input stream:

```
std::istream& inputStream = ...;
std::string prefix = ...;
bool inputStreamStartsWithPrefix = ?
```

Sure, we could compute `inputStreamStartsWithPrefix` by writing a for loop. But how to do it idiomatically (without a for loop, with an algorithm)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) in combination with `std::equal` like

```
std::istringstream is("foobar");
std::string prefix = "foo";
bool inputStreamStartsWithPrefix = std::equal(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), std::istream_iterator<char>(is));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to read from the stream anyways, so you're probably better off just reading the from stream, and then checking the contents of what you just read to see if it begins with the string.

Trying to do anything else will make it very difficult to do whatever you intend to do when the stream doesn't start with that string. (unless, of course, if your intention is something like quitting the program)

Comment: Unless those streams are so large that they don't fit into memory . . .